# inline onclick function(this) not calling jQuery methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I run into trouble when dealing with onclick event.
My HTML:

```
<div>
  <button onclick="sound(this)">Listen</button> 
  <audio class="audio" src="example.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

My JS (jQuery):

```
function sound(element){
  $audio = element.siblings('.audio').first();
  $audio.trigger('play');
}
```

The thing is the audio file not played.
I also made some tests.

```
function sound(element){
   alert(element.tagName); -> it worked
   alert(element.parent().tagName); -> not worked and so on with siblings() or next()
```

Something must be wrong. Please help me out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `element` (the `this` that you're passing) is a native DOM element, not a jQuery wrapper!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
function sound(element){
  $audio = element.siblings('.audio').first();
  $audio.trigger('play');
}
```

Try this

```
function sound(element){
  $audio = $(element).siblings('.audio').first(); //here 'element' is just a DOM element you have to wrap 'element' in jquery wrapper.
  $audio.trigger('play');
}
```

Comment: It will be good to mention that `onclick=""` is outdated way to add event handler.